# Editing /etc/sudoers to allow Winbind Group members to Only sudo to 1 Local User

Tags: permissions, sudo, user-management, active-directory

I have multiple Ubuntu Linux hosts that need to connect to Active Directory for user management (unfortunately an actual LDAP server was not an option here...) and have configured Winbind to handle authentication, and my `%sudoers` group entry works fine:

```
## Allow AD members of the service group restricted user access to that account
%sudoers ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

I have allowed password authentication in the ssh config and have added the following entry to my sudoers file for the account:

```
%service ALL=(service:service) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

This doesn't even find the group even though the `sudoers` group and the `service` groups are at the same level in the directory tree on the AD server.  When I do this:

```
%domain.local\\service ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

...members of the `service` group are able to log in and have full sudo rights, including root which is unacceptable, and already covered  by the `sudoers` group and entry.  Alternatively when I do this:

```
%domain.local\\service ALL=(service:service) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

...members are unable to sudo to any user.  As for the service user, here is the /etc/passwd entry for the `service` user:

```
service:x:1001:16777230::/opt/service:/bin/bash
```

Per the [Sudoers Man Page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) this last entry should probably work, but for some reason it doesn't.  Also, the `%service` should also probably cover both local and AD provided membership but it doesn't seem to.  When I create this user since there is already a group in the directory server named `service` here is how I am creating the `service` user account:

```
useradd -d /opt/service -g service service
```

Here is the output of `sudo -l` for a member of the group:

```
[user.test@server ~]$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for user.test on this host:
    requiretty, !visiblepw, always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS
    DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1
    PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE
    LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY
    LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL
    LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY",
    secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User user.test may run the following commands on this host:
    (service : service) NOPASSWD: /opt/service
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: "This doesn't even allow members to log in" ... sudoers has nothing to do with login via SSH. For each of these settings, what is the output of `sudo -l` for an applicable user?

Comment: [user.test@aaamecldtbwp02 ~]$ sudo -l service
sudo: list: command not found

Comment: No, just `sudo -l` without a command, and edit your question to include more information, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.  We needed to set the login shell and path to the sudoers entry for the `service` user's home like so:

```
%domain.local\\service ALL=(service) NOPASSWD:/bin/bash, /opt/service/*
```

Now we are able to enter the following to become the `service` user:

```
$ sudo -i -u service
$ whoami
service
$ pwd
/opt/service
```